# Unable to return sorted array in Laravel with preserved keys

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-collection

I have below array:

```
$arr[123]['price'] = 100;
$arr[456]['price'] = 500;
$arr[100]['price'] = 1000;
$arr[511]['price'] = 200;
```

Now I want to sort it by price, so I did below operation:

```
$arr = collect($arr);

$sorted = $arr->sortBy('price');
```

Array gets sorted & dd($sorted) gives me below result:

```
Collection {#957 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    123 => array:1 [▼
      "price" => 100
    ]
    511 => array:1 [▼
      "price" => 200
    ]
    456 => array:1 [▼
      "price" => 500
    ]
    100 => array:1 [▼
      "price" => 1000
    ]
  ]
}
```

But when I return above sorted array, it gets sort again by keys:

```
return $sorted;
```

Above outputs:

```
{
  "100": {
    "price": 1000
  },
  "123": {
    "price": 100
  },
  "456": {
    "price": 500
  },
  "511": {
    "price": 200
  }
}
```

I know **values()** will solve this but I do not want reindexing. I want returned array in below format only:

```
{
      "123": {
        "price": 100
      },
      "511": {
        "price": 200
      },
      "456": {
        "price": 500
      },
      "100": {
        "price": 1000
      }
    }
```

Does any one have any idea how do I get this? I also tried **$preserveKeys** flag but no success.

I am using Laravel 5.8.35

Comment: Why would the order change when you return it?

Comment: Please check before returning $sorted , you may be assigning another or same array again to $sorted variable.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Use your browser's DevTools Network tab to take a look at the response payload, it is sorted the way you want, but most likely your browser or some plugin responsible for displaying JSON re-sorts it.

Comment: @kerbholz thanks. JSON viewer chrome extension was reordering it.

Answer (score 1):

For PHP [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> An array in PHP is actually **an ordered map**.

So the collection result is ordered.

However, I think your response is JSON object.

> An object is a member of the type Object. It is **an unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method.

So if you need the index and the order, maybe you can construct the structure like this:

```
[
      {
        "index": "123",
        "price": 100
      },
      {
        "index": "511",
        "price": 200
      },
      {
        "index": "456",
        "price": 500
      },
      {
        "index": "100",
        "price": 1000
      }
    ]
```

So this is an ordered array, and every element is object.

Comment: Order seems to remain the same https://3v4l.org/gXcCT

Comment: @vivek_23 you can try it in postman, it will return unordered json object. For insurance purposes, I recommend to use array with object.

Comment: And the link you post is in php, `json_encode()` return a string. What I said is in javascript to browser.

Comment: In Postman, I get a correct response. https://imgur.com/a/1ueNbVG

Comment: Also, when javascript receives this in browser, it will be a JSON string and not a json object, unless explicitly parsed using JSON.parse(), because everything you send over a network is a string, either serialized or unserialized.

Comment: @vivek_23 JSON libraries are free to rearrange the order of the elements. I remember two years ago, I have tested it.and it didn't work in postman. Now I have tried it few times in postman, and it is ordered. But when I try it in browser. it is not ordered. And my browser is chrome, the version is 80.0.3

Comment: So postman maybe reordering it? And actually the order of an object does not matter because they are identified by property.

Comment: @vivek_23 It seems it is because after  response JSON string the browser use `JSON.parse()` to change JSON string to object, and the object is unordered. @Oluwatobi Samuel Omisakin I'm not sure about why postman works when it become object.

Comment: @TsaiKoga Yes, just saw that. The JSON.parse() at the front end changes the order as we can't depend on hashed data as ordering could be anything. Then OP can send data in the way you suggested it.

Answer (score 1):

you may use

```
return $sorted->values()->all();
```

as mentioned in official documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby